# How to skip first rows and all empty rows after that in specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a way of get all info from several excel files in to one file, but with some specific needs.
I need to delete the first 21 rows of all files except the first one, and at the same time I need to delete all rows that are empty in column "E".

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

#all files in directory (NOT SURE IF I CAN OPTIMIZE THE CODE WITH THIS)
#AM NOT USING THIS LINE AT THE MOMENT
#excel_names = glob.glob('*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx')

# filenames
excel_names = ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in 
excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first (NOT WORKING)
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first (NOT WORKING)
frames[21:] = [df[21:] for df in frames[21:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

The file is created, the concatenate ocours, but it isnt deleting the first 21 rows of all other files than the first. And I need your help to figure out how to delete all rows that have the cell on the "E" column blank.

Great thanks to all.

Comment: the frames list, is it a list of dataframe?

Comment: thanks for your help @Jeril, not sure (newby here) the full code is in the question, i have no other code running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dropping the first 21 rows - you can do this

`frames = [df.iloc[21:, :] for df in frames]`

And to drop all the `NaN` values from column `E` - you can do this

`combined.dropna(subset=["E"], inplace=True)`

Your final code will look something like this -

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

#all files in directory (NOT SURE IF I CAN OPTIMIZE THE CODE WITH THIS)
#AM NOT USING THIS LINE AT THE MOMENT
#excel_names = glob.glob('*JAN_2019-jan.xlsx')

# filenames
excel_names = ["file1.xlsx", "file2.xlsx", "file3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in 
excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first (NOT WORKING)
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first (NOT WORKING)
frames = [df.iloc[21:, :] for df in frames]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)
combined.dropna(subset=["E"], inplace=True)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

To drop the first 21 rows from all dataframes except the first one - you can do this -

```
frames_2 = [df.iloc[21:, :] for df in frames[1:]]
#And combine them separately
combined = pd.concat([frames[0], *frames_2])
```

To exclude the character "-" from your dataframe -

```
combined = combined[~combined['E'].isin(['-'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mortz, i tried the code, and gave me the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 15, in <module>
    frames = [df.iloc[21:, :] for df in frames]
NameError: name 'frames' is not defined

Comment: I am assuming you ran all the code before this line as is - i.e. up to `frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in 
excels]`

Comment: comented it out, sorry, i am new to python, at this moment the error is the following:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 20, in <module>
    combined.dropna(subset=["E"], inplace=True)
NameError: name 'combined' is not defined

Comment: You will have to run the `dropna` after running this line  - `combined = pd.concat(frames)`

Comment: sorry for all the trouble, i got another error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 24, in <module>
    combined.dropna(subset=["E"], inplace=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3052, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
KeyError: ['E']

Comment: Looks like your `combined` dataframe does not have a column named `E` - You can take a look at the columns in `combined` with `print(combined.columns)` - Most likely, you will get an index object. If your index is `[0, 1, 2, ...]` for example and the column you want to drop is the 5th column - you can say - `combined.dropna(subset=[4], inplace=True)`

Comment: thanks for the help
i run the code and it run great, two more questions if you have time
is it possible to only delete the 21 rows in every file except the first one?
and the other, is it possible to delete also cells in columns E that contain the same caractar "-"

Answer (score 0):

Drops rows 2 to 21 (index begin at 0):
df.drop(df.index[[1,20]])

for delete all rows that contains null in column "E":
df.dropna(subset=['E'])

Comment: thanks for the help @Felix Martinez, i am going to try this